# Variable inside function

Tags: java

I'm trying to access a variable `X` that's inside a function, but I cannot seem to access it.
I have a function "Action()"

```
public void Action(){

  ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

  try {
    String response = null;
    try {
      response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx.php",
                                                  postParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String result = response.toString();  

    //parse json data
    try {
      returnString = "";
      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      for (int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
              ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
              ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
              ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear"));
        X = json_data.getInt("birthyear");
        returnString += "\n" + json_data.getString("Time") + " -> "+ json_data.getInt("Value");
      }
    } catch(JSONException e){
      Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    } catch(Exception e){
      Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          
    }   
  }
}
```

I want to be able to access the variable "X" outside the method but it keeps telling me that X is not declared.

Answer (score 1):

In Java (and most other languages) there are so called "scopes", let's limit to "blocks" here.
A block is basically an aggregation of single expressions enclosed in `{` and `}`.

Have a look at this pseudo-example:

```
{ // outer block
    int a = 1;
    { // inner block
        int b = 1;
    }
}
```

in the inner block you can access both `a` and `b` whereas in the outer block you cannot *see* `b`, which is why you can neither access nor change it (so you only see `a` in the outer block)

Answer (score 0):

> Declare the X instance variable or local variable inside the method according to requirement.

If you want to access this variable from any instance method then declare it instance variable or If you want to make the scope to local then declare it in method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ....
   private int X;   //Way to declare the instance variable.
  ....

  private void methodName() {
  {
        private int X;   //Way to declare the local variable.
  }
}
```

In Java you need to declare the variable before use it. You are initializing it without declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

```
void method(){

   int foo; //this is called variable declaration

   //some where else in code
   foo = 12; //this is called initialization of the variable

   int fooBar = foo + bar;

}
```

The above example shows the METHOD LEVEL SCOPE. The variable `foo` will not be accessible outside the scope of method.

- Class Scope
- Loop Scope
- Method Scope

[Vairable scopes in Java](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)